# Private methods causing jasmine tests to fail

Tags: jasmine

I'm trying to test a function similar to the one below using Jasmine

```
closure.respond = function (value){ 
if(value)
{
    thisIsAPrivateMethod();

}
thisIsAPublicMethod();

}
```

My Test looks like this

```
    it('will display the calendar widget when value is true', function(){

    value=true
    closure.respond(value);
    expect(closure.thisIsAPublicMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
)

})
```

Whenever I run the test I get an exception in the jasmine test runner that states that a method that is called inside the private function does not exist. (Object # has no method 'methodName'
)

I'm not concerned with the inner workings of the private function, how can I just ignore that call?

Can I ignore it? Obviously I can't/shouldn't spy on it as it is private. 
Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points, you cant test call on methode that are not visible from outside, just because they are not visible. And you shouldn't test the inner behavior of your object you wanna test.

Comment: Agreed. My problem is that in testing closure.respond, internally it calls a private method which is then throwing an error due to it having a dependency that has not been declared. How far down the call stack do I need to go?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem, but why do you have an undeclared dependency. You should mock/stub the dependency and inject it into your closure. Or if its a global one just mock it like this `jasmine.spy(window, 'dependency').andReturn(someMockImplenetaion)`

Comment: The problem was that I was trying not to concern myself with the implementation within the private function,however, to get this test working I do need to know what the private function is doing as it is executed during the test, my concern is over the number of dependencies that seem to appear the further down the call chain I go.  I'll get there eventually. Thanks for your insight.